# Debug the inclusion of a specific jar file inside a war file

Tags: java, maven

I have the following project structure

```
   A (testlib removed)
  / \
 V   V
 B   C
  \  /
    V
    D (packs to war)
```

Basically, project A is a dependency of B and C which are in turn dependencies of project D

Initially I had the a library say `testlib` inside project A. However, I removed this library in the project A pom.

I did the following:

```
1. mvn clean install on project A (`testlib` remove)
2. mvn install on project B
3. mvn install on project C
4. mvn install on Project D, which creates a `war` say `d.war`.
```

When I open the `d.war` archive, I can see that `testlib` is present inside `WEB-INF/lib`

I tried mvn `dependency:tree` on all the projects, I couldn't find `testlib` in any of the projects. 
I want to understand the possible causes of `testlib` being included in the `war` file or if there is a better way to debug..

Comment: Can you also add the output of the `dependency:tree` command on the `D` project?

Comment: Sorry, the projects and the dependencies are part of an internal project, so I can't add the output.

Comment: i assume that you meant "Basically, project A is a dependency of (not on) B and C which are in turn dependencies of (not on) project D" -correct?

Comment: @OhadR You are right, I changed the description.

Answer (score 1):

what is the version of A?

if it is NOT a "SNAPSHOT" (or in other words it is a "RELEASE"; meaning it does not end with "SNAPSHOT") then maven will not update your other projects B and C with the new A.

Comment: A is a snapshot. Actually, I can see that the new version of A is being applied to B and C. Just when it comes to packaging to jar, the `testlib` library is included in the war.

Comment: so maybe another JAR is dependent on "testlib"?

Comment: I checked that the jar file for `testlib` was present in `target-server-side` folder, I deleted from it and then again followed the steps I mentioned earlier. It seems to work. But can you help me to  understand what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your local .m2 repository inside the pom of project A whether the testlib is still mentioned.
try by remove the folder of project A from the .m2 and doing a clean install of A and D